# spring framework classreader exception

Tags: java, spring

I'm working with a legacy application (Java 1.8 on Ubuntu 20.04) and I'm getting this unusual ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 9322 out of bounds for length 336
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.config.java.internal.parsing.asm.AsmConfigurationParser.parse(AsmConfigurationParser.java:87)
    at org.springframework.config.java.internal.parsing.asm.AsmConfigurationParser.parse(AsmConfigurationParser.java:75)
    at org.springframework.config.java.internal.factory.support.AsmJavaConfigBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AsmJavaConfigBeanDefinitionReader.java:70)
    at org.springframework.config.java.internal.process.InternalConfigurationPostProcessor.parseAnyConfigurationClasses(InternalConfigurationPostProcessor.java:128)
    at org.springframework.config.java.internal.process.InternalConfigurationPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(InternalConfigurationPostProcessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.config.java.context.JavaConfigApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(JavaConfigApplicationContext.java:121)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:362)
    at org.springframework.config.java.context.JavaConfigApplicationContext.<init>(JavaConfigApplicationContext.java:80)
    at org.xper.app.acq.TimeServer.main(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas about what's causing this problem?

Comment: TL;DR old `asm` library vs. new java.

Comment: You use STL like IDE?

Answer (score 0):

This was on me: I had installed the JRE 1.8 but I didn't explicitly add it to eclipse so I was running on JRE 11.